# How to insert missing date time value while resampling frequencies more efficient?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am just learning programming. What I am now doing is to resample data with date time frequencies as shown below.

```
             loctimestamp  volume       Date
0 2011-01-04 08:01:03.820  2994.0 2011-01-04
1 2011-01-04 08:01:03.940     2.0 2011-01-04
2 2011-01-04 08:01:04.240     4.0 2011-01-04
3 2011-01-04 08:01:04.560    12.0 2011-01-04
4 2011-01-04 08:01:04.580     1.0 2011-01-04
5 2011-01-04 08:01:04.690     1.0 2011-01-04
6 2011-01-04 08:01:04.700     5.0 2011-01-04
7 2011-01-04 08:01:04.880     5.0 2011-01-04
8 2011-01-04 08:01:05.090    61.0 2011-01-04
9 2011-01-04 08:01:07.140     4.0 2011-01-04
```

Here I listed only the first 2 columns and 10 rows of my whole data, which has more than 1m lines. What I expect is a resampling with 1s frequency and sum the volume, as shown below:

```
             loctimestamp  volume              
      2011-01-04 08:01:04  2996.0
      2011-01-04 08:01:05    28.0
      2011-01-04 08:01:06    61.0
      2011-01-04 08:01:07     0.0
      2011-01-04 08:01:08     4.0
```

This result is achieved by using pandas.DataFrame.resample() function. This function will insert the missing frequencies between first time and last time for each day, like the 2011-01-04 08:01:07 line above.

My work now is to transform the whole calculation from Pandas to PySpark. PySpark does resample the data more efficient but I can't find a way to efficiently insert the missing frequencies like what pandas did.

what I have tried in spark for this is:

```
  #first find the first and last frequency for each day, the data has been 
#pre resampled here to seconds, col("pre_resampled") is unix time in second 
#form and fre is set to 1s
fre=1
max_time_for_each_date=(df.orderBy('Date')
                          .groupBy('Date')
                          .agg({'pre_resampled': "max"})).collect()
min_time_for_each_date=(df.orderBy('Date')
                          .groupBy('Date')
                          .agg({'pre_resampled': "min"})).collect()

  #create a dataframe with all the frequencies inserted, I tried the 
#spark.DataFrame.union() function to create this dataframe which seems to be 
#less efficient(I also put the code here).
#ref = spark.range(min_time_for_each_date[0][1], 
#                  max_time_for_each_date[0][1]+ 1,
#                  fre
#                 ).toDF('pre_resampled')
#i=1
#while i < len(max_time_for_each_date):
#    ref = ref.union(spark.range(min_time_for_each_date[i][1], 
#                                max_time_for_each_date[i][1]+ 1, 
#                                fre
#                               ).toDF('pre_resampled'))
#    i += 1
list1=[]
i=0
while i < len(max_time_for_each_date):
    list1.extend(list(range(min_time_for_each_date[i][1], 
                            max_time_for_each_date[i][1]+1, 
                            fre)))
    i += 1

ref = (spark.createDataFrame(list1, IntegerType())
           .withColumnRenamed('value','pre_resampled'))

#combine the created DataFrame ref and the main DataFrame
df= (ref
    .join(df, 'pre_resampled', 'left')
    .orderBy('pre_resampled','loctimestamp')
    .withColumn('resampled', col('pre_resampled').cast('timestamp')))
```

this code works, output is in fact what I need. the problem is if the fre is set to 1 second, it will sometimes end up with a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` or a `Time Limit Exceed`.

also tried:

```
schema = df.schema

@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def udf_resample(df,fre='S'):
    result = df.resample(fre, on = 'loctimestamp').sum()
    return df.reset_index()

df.groupBy('Date').apply(udf_resample).show()
```

this shows me `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'resample'`, I think the reason is not all the pandas functions are available in pandas_udf, am I correct?

What I am trying to do now is to add the spark.executer.memory or the spark.drive.memory.

Any other idea?

Comment: The short answer, is that shouldn't do this -- not _exactly_ this.  Why do you want rows that have zero volume? You shouldn't need them. After all, they're all zero!

Comment: Actually this is only used for comparing the result with the previous result which is entirely created with pandas to avoid mistakes before starting the main processing.

Comment: Rather than recreating a wasteful data format that you don't need, create a new method of validation that works on two formats. Maybe sum volumes up to a day?

Comment: The error message on the pandasUDF has to be read differently. df seems to be a tuple not a DataFrame.